# Acessar /index.php como /index (sem o ".php")

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite

Utilizando expressões regulares, consigo verificar páginas index.html como index mas não paginas index.php como index.
Meu .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index$ index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Dentro do meu apache, no endereço `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, tenho o virtual host padrão e tenho o virtual host esms.com com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@esms.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/meus_projetos/E-SMS-DEVEL"
    ServerName www.esms.com
    ServerAlias esms.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

## AllowOverride All

```
    <Directory /var/www/html/meus_projetos/E-SMS-DEVEL>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Baseando nessas informações, gostaria de ajuda para entender o que estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: Bom dia, a resposta resolveu o seu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Não seria só trocar o .html por .php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Ou pode tentar fazer isto que serviria pra qualquer arquivo php:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Você pode também tentar usar o [mod_negotiation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html)